# Populate a powershell array with values, one per line, without needing quotes?

Tags: powershell

It's common for my scripts to iterate over a list of items in an array and these items are usually pasted from elsewhere like excel or another script. I currently populate my array like this:

```
$vmlist = @(
#group 1
"vmname1"
"vmname2"
# group 2
"vmname3"
"vmname4"
#"vmname5"
)
```

Pros are that I can easily add comments or comment out lines with #.

Cons is having to manually add the quotes. I usually resort to using regular expressions in notepad++ to add the quotes, but others that use my scripts will often just mess up the quotes (missing or mismatch).

Is there a powershell trick for me to leave the items list unquoted like this, ideally still with support for commenting.

```
$vmlist = @(
vmname1
vmname2
vmname3
vmname4
)
```

I guess I could do something like this and post-process it by splitting by \r\n, trimming, removing empty lines, ignoring text after a #, and finally storing it into an array of the same name, but curious if there is a smarter/better way.

```
$vmlist = "
vmname1
vmname2
vmname3
vmname4
vmname5
"
```

Comment: Try something like this rather `$vmlist = @("vmname1 vmname2 vmname3 vmname4")` and just double quote before the first and after the last values, but putting values on separate lines seems to still work and keep it an array data type.

Answer (score 2):

Use [here-string](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-here-string-preserve-text-formatting) to paste a text from elsewhere:

> To define a here-string in PowerShell, you need to use the `@`
>   character followed by either a single or double quote and then a
>   newline. To end, close the quotes and add another `@` on a newline:

```
$vmlist = @"
#group 1
vmname1
vmname2
# group 2
vmname3
vmname4
#vmname5
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine -notmatch "^#"
$vmlist
```

> ```
> vmname1
> vmname2
> vmname3
> vmname4
> ```

- ***Pros*** are that I can easily add comments or comment out lines with `#`;
- ***Cons* are *eliminated***…

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to do inside an inline array.  I've had similar issues myself and have resorted to using a text file as a souce list.  Something like this should do what you want it to:

```
Get-Content C:\Installs\SourceFiles.txt | Where {$_ -notlike "#*"} | Where {$_.trim() -ne ""} | ForEach {
    Write-Host $_
    #Do Your Stuff Here
}
```

[image]